# An error while submitting app to app store "ERROR ITMS-90455"

Tags: ios, app-store, watchos-2

This error show up when I am submitting the app to the store.What I have done is I have re-create the watch kit after I found that my project doesn't need to have glance interface.I have remove the target and old file.It have no problem when I execute on the device.

Error ITMS-90455: "Invalid WatchKit App Bundle.The value '2.1' for MinimunOSVersion key in info.plist in bundle 'appname.watchkitapp'is not supported."

Comment: change `WATCHOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` from 2.1 to 2.0

Comment: Always search for an error message before posting such a question.

Comment: my bad sorry @rmaddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check go `WatchAppTarget` -> `Build Settings` -> `Deployment` -> `WATCHOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` change from 2.1 to 2.0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the watchOS deployment target from 2.1 to 2.0.

You can find it in Project Settings -> "Watch App Target" -> Build Settings -> Deployment -> watchOS Deployment Target